# Order of citation numbers in text

Tags: citing, natbib

I have a problem, regarding the order of citations in the text. I use unsrt to get numbers for citations in the order of appearance in the text. However, I am facing two problems, as you can see from the image which I attached.

1. References appear in the text in the same order as in the .tex-file, but I want to let them appear in increasing numbers (e.g. 344,343,203 -> 203,343,344).
2. More than two following reference numbers should be displayed not in a row but with a dash (e.g. 33,134,135 -> 133-135).

[image: Example with wrong reference ordering]

In my preamble I am using those commands to generate the appearance in the text

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibpunct{ }{}{,}{s}{}{;}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
```

I am citing with

```
\cite{Name2015, Name2016}
```

And my bibliography is generated with

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\footnotesize{#1}}
\bibliography{literature}
```

Can you help me to get rid of the two problems?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so after some google searches I came to the idea to have a look in the package documentation itself...
I fixed both issues by changing the package load to:

```
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

By that, the citing numbers are sorted within the text and compressed.

Comment: And you should use `unsrtnat` as the bib style, not `unsrt`.